# Preserve focus on input field on enter keypress

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have two react components. `App` renders out an input element, whose defaultValue is fed from the `Parent` component. On enter keyup event, I send the current value of the input up to `Parent`, which updates the prop that gets sent down as the new value.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

interface IAppProps {
  InputVal: number;
  onEnter: (num: number) => void;
}

const Parent: React.FC = () => {
  const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = React.useState(1);
  const grabVal = (val: number) => {
    console.log("New value::", val);
    setCurrentValue(val);
  };

  return <App InputVal={currentValue} onEnter={grabVal} />;
};

const App: React.FC<IAppProps> = ({ InputVal, onEnter }) => {
  const handleEnterKey = (e: any) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      onEnter(Number((e.target as HTMLInputElement).value));
    }
  };
  return (
    <input
      onKeyUp={handleEnterKey}
      key={InputVal}
      defaultValue={InputVal as any}
    />
  );
};

render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

The problem is that every enter key press, the focus on the input gets lost and I have to tab in again every time. How do I prevent this from happening.

Things I can't use:

1. autofocus property - reason being there will be other buttons next to the input that does the same functionality as the enter keypress. So autofocusing on the input will interfere with that.
2. Use onChange - since I only want to send the new value up to `Parent` on enter key press and later on tab off.

Running example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-6bd5e

Comment: I just tried your sandbox and it works as expected? Enter some numbers, press enter key and I can type again without tabbing in again

Comment: I was temporarily trying something else. I've updated the code, please have a look now.